# How can I see the current upload and download speed when using Internet via Bluetooth tethering?

Tags: data-monitoring, bluetooth-tethering, samsung-galaxy-s-23

I use Internet on my S23 Ultra phone via Bluetooth tethering. How can I see the current upload and download speed (i.e., monitoring the current use) when using Internet via Bluetooth tethering?

[Network Speed - Internet Speed Meter - Indicator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.evozi.network&hl=en_US&gl=US) doesn't see traffic from Bluetooth tethering .